# Google Auth is not working in flutter webview

Tags: flutter, webview, android-webview, flutter-web-browser

[image]

Tried to login in boat website via google through flutter webview, getting above issue everytime.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `userAgent: 'random'` when init webview

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).